# XCode 7.0b5: LaunchImage

Tags: xcode, launchimage

I found LaunchImage in Images.xcassets. I inserted my png file and it worked fine. Then I updated it and it is not shown again. Only a white screen appeared. I removed it completely, inserted it again. Does not help.
The recomendation for portrait is 1242x2208. So I created exacly this size. No change.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use the `LaunchScreen.xib` as a launch screen?

Check out my answer to this question because you may have a similar issue:
[Landscape Launch Images on Xcode 7 madness - [FIXED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352236/landscape-launch-images-on-xcode-7-madness/32353058#32353058)

Comment: When creating a new project with XCode 7 I get a LaunchScreen.storyboard. When I create it from XCode 6.4 I get LaunchScreen.xib. I copied them to my existing project, but none of them are shown after startup. Do I need to insert some additional code (Swift)? I only want to show a simple png file.

Comment: Yes, go into your project settings, in the general section you should find "App Icons and Launch Images". Make sure to select the correct Launch Screen file there.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I had more than one LaunchScreen item. And the unknown was selected and empty.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen.xib has a higher priority than LaunchImage.

If you want to make LaunchImage work,you should first remove LaunchScreen.xib or LaunchScreen.storyboard in your project.

[image]